# attempt to call method 'insert' (a nil value)

Tags: lua, coronasdk

How come I get a `attempt to call method 'insert' (a nil value)` error on the line containing `insert`?

Changing it to `instance.sprites = bg` does make it work, but I want to return all sprites in a separate table (sprites).

```
local writingTool = {}

local _W, _H = display.contentWidth, display.contentHeight

function writingTool:new()
    local instance = {}
    instance.index = writingTool
    setmetatable(instance, self)

    instance.sprites = {}

    local bg = display.newImage("images/backgrounds/wooden_bg.png")
    bg.x = _W/2
    bg.y = _H/2
    instance.sprites:insert(bg)
    return instance
end

return writingTool
```

**Edit:** Trying `instance.sprites.bg = bg` does not work either. Give this error:

```
bad argument #-2 to 'insert' (Proxy expected, got nil)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
instance.index = writingTool
```

Should be

```
instance.__index = writingTool
```

Though I would remove the above line and implement it in the one below like so:

`setmetatable(instance,{__index=writingTool})`

Also, `t:insert()` or `t.insert()` aren't defined by ***default***, to insert elements into a table you use the `table.insert` function as defined below:

> table.insert (table, [pos,] value)

so you should have `table.insert(instance.sprites,bg)`. So with these modifications your function should look like:

```
function writingTool:new()
    local instance = { sprites = {} }
    setmetatable(instance, {__index = wirtingTool})
    local bg = display.newImage("images/backgrounds/wooden_bg.png")
    bg.x = _W/2
    bg.y = _H/2
    table.insert(instance.sprites,bg)
    return instance
end
```

Comment: Neither `bg` or `instance.sprites` are nil

Comment: @Sunkas could you humor me and run the complete snippet I posted above?

Comment: @Sunkas oops, tables `{}` by themselves don't have `.insert` defined. You have to use `table.insert(my_table,my_value)`. Or `my_table[#my_table+1] = my_value`

Comment: Thanks. Hower, both of them seem to get the following error: bad `argument #-2 to 'insert' (Proxy expected, got nil)` Example code: `instance.sprites[#instance.sprites+1] = bg`

Comment: @Sunkas you're welcome, sorry I missed it for so long... to much Python of late!